# How to solve Node.js npm npx problem: You are using npm 2.15.12 but I'm updated?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I'm having a problem with npm. I created a React.js proyect using

```
npx create-react-app my_app
```

And it worked without any problem. Now, I started another (in another folder) also with npx create-react-app my_app, but now, there's an error that says:

> "You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
> Please update to npm 6 or higher for a better, fully supported experience."

And if I let the installation to complete, a bunch of errors come up:
"> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\PrimerEntregaFinal\my_app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\core-js

> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\PrimerEntregaFinal\my_app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\PrimerEntregaFinal\my_app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

(...) a bunch more like those in different dependencies of /node_modules (...)
And finally:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-audit" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts@0.9.x"
npm ERR! node v16.13.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.12 postinstall script 'node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the core-js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs core-js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls core-js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\PrimerEntregaFinal\my_app\npm-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
```

I just don't understand what changed and why it's happening?
I tried:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs
2. deleted the npm_cache
3. Using on CMD ***npx where npm*** to see where I have installed npm, showing:

   > C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
4. There I tried:

   > C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm -v
   > 8.3.0 (so it's up to date)

What should I do? what am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: how many node versions do you have installed on your machine? can your run nvm ls?

Comment: @sandeep.kgp I tried and this is the result (I tried npm ls, since nvm is not recognized, I'm on windows, so maybe there's a different command?)
C:\Users\Usuario>npm ls
Usuario@ C:\Users\Usuario
+-- canvas-sketch-cli@1.11.14
+-- canvas-sketch-util@1.10.0
+-- gsap@3.5.1
+-- latest@0.2.0
+-- lil-gui@0.15.0
`-- react-router-dom@5.3.0

Comment: Well obviously I was doing sth wrong, I installed nvm, had a bunch of version problems somehow, reinstalled from powershell and run "nvm ls", and this is what it showed up:
PS C:\Users\Usuario> nvm ls

    17.3.0
    16.13.1

Comment: ok..try running command 'nvm use 16.13.1' and then run npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\Entrega05> nvm use 16.13.1
exit status 5: Access denied.

exit status 1: Can not create a file that already exists.

Comment: I tried creating a react app the other way (without npx):
>npm i -g create-react-app
>create-react-app my_app

and that way the error of npm version 2.15.16 does not appear.. maybe there's some problem with npx?

Comment: after npm i -g create-react-app, did it work?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it and it worked. What I can't figure out now is what is the problem with npx and npm

Comment: okay..can you try npx clear-npx-cache and then npx create-react-app

Comment: and npx create-react-app@latest my-app

Comment: Those didn't work either :(
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\Entrega05> npx clear-npx-cache
Need to install the following packages:
  clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) y
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\Entrega05> npx create-react-app@latest my-app
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\Entrega05\my-app.
You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to npm 6 or higher for a better, fully supported experienc

Comment: try running cmd as administrator ?

Comment: do you have any .nvmrc file in that directory ?

Comment: I checked and I have a .nvmrc in kind off a sibling directory, I mean: I'm trying to create-react-app in:
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\React\Entregas\Entrega05
And I have that .nvmrc file in 
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\Solidity\Teoria\ProyectoPruebaReactSolidity\node_modules\is-generator-function

Comment: the sibling directory shouldn't interfere..I'm out of ideas now...if you get the solution somehow please let me know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone still needs help with this, I solved it.
I wasn't being able to find where was the outdated file that was causing so much trouble, so I ran the command `npm list npm@2.15.12` (try on your CMD as admin and not as admin, also in the powershell, I tried everywhere).
That command showed me:

```
    C:\Users\Usuario
     --latest@0.2.0
       --npm@2.15.12
```

So at least now I knew that it was somewhere inside "Usuario", but I didn't know exactly where to look. Then I saw that I had a node_modules folder in there (when I already had it elsewhere) and deleted it.
That's it, that solved my problem.

Hope someone finds it usefull too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue try removing `node_modules` from `C:\\Users\\Usuario\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js`

`npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"`

Comment: Hi! I tried that, but as soon as I do that, then if I try npx create-react-app, it won't work because it says that npm-cli.js is missing